Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS not going into sleep mode anymore
My laptop (Dell Inspiron 16 5620) with Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS does not go into sleep mode anymore. I noticed this, since the battery was empty the next day after closing the lid. This might be related to a distribution upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, since I think this occurred the first afterwards. Before everything worked perfectly fine and it still works on the Windows partition on the same device. Reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS again did not solve the problem.
I already read a lot in forums, so here is a list of what I have tried already:

Setting


HandleLidSwitch=suspend

or

HandleLidSwitch=hibernate

in /etc/systemd/logind.conf did not change anything. As usual, the screen turns off when closing the lid, but the laptop still consumes a lot of power.

The deep entry in /sys/power/mem_sleep is missing, but I cannot just fix it, since


echo deep > mem_sleep

as root user results in

bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument


A colleague told me that he once had a similar problem where the touchpad kept waking up the computer, so I tried to disable it in /proc/acpi/wakeup. I do not know how to identify the touchpad but I have to tried to disable every option in that file and even disabled all options at the same time but I could still wake up my computer via the touchpad. Also disabling it in the Ubuntu settings just disabled it in the unlocked mode, so the waking up still works.

Also just running

sudo systemctl suspend

did have the same result, so it seems that the sleep mode does not work in general.
I surely missed some points I tried as well but these should be the most important ones. I hope that someone can help me! Thank you very much in advance!
